# angular $http headers not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jwt

My client side look like this :

```
$http(
       {
            method: 'GET',
            url: myConfig.serverUrl + '/getUserId',
            data: '',
            headers: { 'Authorization' : '21321313'},
       });
```

Server side in Node js and express :

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization');
next();
```

});

But request not set the Authorization value
`OPTIONS /getUserId HTTP/1.1.
Host: xxxxx.
Connection: keep-alive.
Pragma: no-cache.
Cache-Control: no-cache.
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET.
Origin: http://localhost:9000.
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36.
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization.
Accept: */*.
Referer: http://localhost:9000/.
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch.
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6.`

I have try many ways but none of them work.
When i try to to that with postman i get the value so i think my problem in my angular side but i cant figure out what is the problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue in server side,
In "OPTIONS" API call no need to check Authorization

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `authorization type` something like `'Authorization', 'Basic ZWx1c3VhcmlvOnlsYWNsYXZl'`

Answer (score 0):

In Basic authentication, base64 are used to decode the username and password. So, inject and use Base64 to encode the username and password

```
var token = Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + token;
```